# AttributeError: 'GridLayout' object has no attribute 'print_text'

Tags: python, kivy

I am just starting with screen manager programming in Kivy. I am trying to call a function "print_text()" from .kv file when I press a button named "Press Me!". Am I calling it in the wrong way like `input.<function>?` or Am I doing something wrong with my python code?
Note: I am able to switch the screens.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager

    screen_one: screen_one
    screen_two: screen_two

    ScreenOne:
        id: screen_one
        name: "screen_one"
        manager: screen_manager

    ScreenTwo:
        id: screen_two
        name: "screen_two"
        manager: screen_manager

<ScreenOne>:
    GridLayout:
        id: input
        rows: 2
        display: entry
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Label:
                text: "Input Your Text"
                size_hint_x: 0.22
                size_hint_y: 0.22

            TextInput:
                id: entry
                size_hint_x: 0.78
                size_hint_y: 0.22

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            Button:
                text: "Press Me!"
                on_press:
                    input.print_text("Screen1:" + entry.text)
            Button:
                text: "SecondScreen"
                on_press:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                    root.manager.current = "screen_two"
<ScreenTwo>:
    GridLayout:
        id: input
        rows: 2
        display: entry
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"           
            Label:
                text: "What's in your Mind?"
                size_hint_x: 0.22
                size_hint_y: 0.22

            TextInput:
                id: entry
                size_hint_x: 0.78
                size_hint_y: 0.22

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            Button:
                text: "Press Me!"
                on_press:
                    input.print_text("Screen2:" + entry.text)
            Button:
                text: "FirstScreen"
                on_press:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                    root.manager.current = "screen_one"
""")

class SampleScreen(GridLayout):
    def print_text(self, text):
        print text

class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):   
    pass

class SimpleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Manager()

myapp = SimpleApp()
myapp.run()
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Root Cause

The `GridLayout` does not has an attribute / method called, `print_text`.

## Solution

The method `print_text()` is implemented in the `class SampleScreen()` in Python script. Therefore, in the kv file, replace the child instance, `GridLayout:` of class rules, `<ScreenOne>:` and `<ScreenTwo>:` with an instance of `SampleScreen:`

### Snippets - kv

```
<ScreenOne>:
    SampleScreen:

...

<ScreenTwo>:
    SampleScreen:
```

Comment: Explaining why is better - else it's just a "copy paste" solution and the reader (OP or anyone else having a similar problem) will not learn much...

Comment: @ikolim : You Made My Day!! Thanks.